# Structuring React Native components and nesting elements for easier use

Tags: react-native, variables, syntax, components

Is there a way in react native to effectively nest the value of this.props.children passed to a component so as to keep files far more tidy and easily accessible.

Take a component called Screen. When this component is used, currently all of the variables required are passed to it in props eg: title, subtitle etc.. This gets extremely messy when there are a lot of variables.

```
<Screen title="Something" subtitle="Something" includeHeader="minimal" ... etc
```

I was hoping for something closer to this.

```
<Screen>
   <Header>
     <Title>
     <Subtitle>
   </Header
   <Content>
   etc..
```

And then able to access these in the Screen component like this.

```
this.header.title
this.header.subtitle
```

For example. This is simpler given the scale of some of these components. Is anything like this possible.

Answer (score 0):

The `children` props is just that, another prop.
This is valid, and is a simple api that anyone would understand:

```
<Screen
  header={
    <Header>
      <Title>
      <Subtitle>
    </Header>
  }
  content={<Content />}
/>
```

You can technically pass everything to the `children` props, and then extract the elements that you want inside screen, and manipulate them inside the Screen component like so:

```
function Header() {
  return "header";
}

function Body() {
  return "body";
}

function Screen({ children }) {
  return React.Children.map(children, child => {
    if (child.type === Header) {
      // do something here, shuffle them around, clone them and change them, delete them
      // you can read their props, put them in variable, pass them to other elements, etc.
      return (<div>Found header! {child}</div>)
    }

    return child
  });
}

function App() {
  return (
    <Screen>
      <div>Hello</div>
      <Header />
      <Body />
    </Screen>
  );
}
```

but will make the public api of the `Screen` component not easy to grasp.